# As music files in a folder, convert them from .ogg to .mp3 (pytnon)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, mp3, converters

There is a folder with music files how to convert them from **.ogg** to **.mp3**

I know there is a way to convert to **ffmpeg**

How to do this in **Python 3** so that it converts all files from a folder (test_music/01.ogg,02.ogg, ...09.ogg)

Comment: Take a look at os.listdir to iterate over it and maybe look into this library to convert it. https://gist.github.com/dgrant/803a957ce86e535fb162

Comment: Thanks!!!  Maybe a stupid question - why are you .ogg to .waw to .mp3 #42,#52 line of code

Comment: I do not know, I didn't write the library

Comment: Thank you! You have written very interesting code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python module `os` and `subprocess` for this if you have `ffmpeg` in PATH:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir(r'FILE_PATH')
for ogg in [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith('.ogg')]:
  subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", ogg, ogg.split(".")[0]+".mp3"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Installed " sudo apt install ffmpeg" and it all worked !!!